# Two ball bounce problem

Tags: arithmetic, physics, puzzle

Two I had an interview, where they have asked me a physics puzzle.
The question was,

If two balls have been dropped at the same time from same height. suppose `Ball A` will start bouncing by `10%` of reducing its height from its very previous bounce. And `Ball B`will start bouncing by `20%` of reducing its height from its very previous bounce. Then how many times they will cross each other?

I have answered him as,

Definitely, `Ball B` bounce less than `Ball A`. So, in this context

if Ball-B starts its bounce from height = x.

Then if I will apply this into a program,

```
int cnt = 0;//Pseudo Code
if(x != 0)
{
x = x * 20 / 100;
 cnt++;
}
```

So, final value of cnt = number of times they will cross each other.

But after this I was thinking that, this many not be correct answer as in first drop,
the `Ball-A` might have bounced of height `x + (x- (height bounced by Ball-B))`.
So, it is not necessary that they might have crossed each other.

Please me understanding this puzzle.

Comment: Surely they cross infinitely many times?

Comment: @user7530 That was my first thought too, but I don't think it's right (see my answer for explanation.)

Answer (score 2):

Your code only measures how many times ball $B$ can bounce before the precision of the computer is unable to distinguish its height from zero.  This seems like an entirely different question from the one you are asked!

A second point is that the question says (in my interpretation) that each bounce of ball $B$ is 80% of the height of the previous one.
So in my interpretation ball $A$ is bouncier than ball $B$.
You seem to agree with this at one point, put then your code suggests that each bounce of ball $B$ is 20% the height of the previous one.

Notice that each ball bounces infinitely many times, with the bounce times forming a convergent geometric series.  This is because the time that a bounce takes to complete is proportional to the speed at the start of the bounce, which is reduced by a constant factor each time.

Denote the time of the first bounce by $t=0$. Let $t_A$ denote the sum of the bounce times for ball $A$, or equivalently the time at which $A$ completes all of its (infinitely many) bounces and begins sitting still. 
Similarly, let $t_B$ denote the sum of the bounce times for ball $A$, or equivalently the time at which $B$ completes all of its (infinitely many) bounces and begins sitting still.

Note that $t_B < t_A$, so ball $B$ has finished bouncing while ball $A$ has bounced only finitely many times.  All of the crossings must therefore happen in the time interval $[0,t_B]$.  Let $t_0 = 0, t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n \le t_B$ list in increasing order the times at which ball $A$ hits the ground during this interval.

For each bounce $[t_i,t_{i+1}]$ of ball $A$, it crosses paths with ball $B$ at most twice: At most once on the way up (because at any given height it is moving faster than ball $B$ is) and at most once on the way down (for the same reason.)  Therefore an upper bound on the number of crossings is given by $2n$.

Because ball $A$'s height in the middle of one of its bounces $[t_i,t_{i+1}]$ is higher than ball $B$ can ever be during that time interval, the only way that there could be fewer than two crossings during the time interval $[t_i,t_{i+1}]$ is in the "degenerate case" that ball $B$ is on the ground at time $t_i$ or at time $t_{i+1}$.  This happens at the beginning of $A$'s first bounce at $t = 0$.  I'll leave it up to you to calculate $t_B$, $n$, and $t_1,\ldots,t_n$, and to see whether this "degenerate case" ever happens again.

Comment: Ball A bouncing against the ground after ball B has come to rest doesn't count as a "crossing"?

Comment: @user7530 No, I don't think it does.

Comment: I don't think $t_B<t_A$ because $1/10\infty=1/5\infty$ in almost all mathematics.

Comment: @SimpleArt  Are you suggesting that $t_A$ and $t_B$ are infinite?  They are sums of convergent geometric series.

Comment: @TrevorWilson Yes, which are both infinitely long, regardless of convergence.

Comment: @SimpleArt  By "infinitely long" do you just mean that the series have infinitely many nonzero terms?  Some infinite series have finite sums, for example geometric series: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series.  The sum of a convergent series is finite, by definition of "convergent", so I don't understand your "regardless of convergence" remark.

Comment: @TrevorWilson This is a geometric series with an infinite amount of finite terms, each representing that the ball is still 'bouncing'.  The sum is finite, but the sum does not tell us how many times the balls past each other.  By "regardless of convergence," I meant that even if it converged, it would never stop bouncing.  For it not to be bouncing, the height of the ball's bounce must be $H_n=0$, which implies that before that bounce, it must have also been bouncing with height $0$.  If it didn't bounce with height $0$ to begin, it will never manage to reach a bounce height of $0$.

Comment: @SimpleArt It's true that the sums $t_A$ and $t_B$ themselves do not tell us how many times the balls pass each other; that's what the last three paragraphs of my answer are for.  However, it is not correct to say that the balls will never stop bouncing.  For example, if the first bounce takes 1 second, and each subsequence bounce takes half the time of the previous, then the bounces will all take place within the first 2 seconds, and after that time, the ball will no longer be bouncing.

Comment: @TrevorWilson But how many times did they bounce in that time?

Comment: @SimpleArt  Infinitely many times.

Comment: @TrevorWilson And if the balls don't hit the ground at the same time, they must cross in between some of the bounces...

Comment: @SimpleArt  I don't know what you are getting at.  First you suggested that the sums $t_A$ and $t_B$ were both infinite.  Now you seem to agree that they are finite, and I hope you also agree that $t_A < t_B$ now.  If so, please read the last three paragraphs of my answer and tell me what, if anything, you think is wrong with them.  Also, please note that I do not consider ball A bouncing against the ground after ball B has come to rest as a "crossing", as I said in my response to user7530.